# Problem to allocate memory outside the main

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

As a beginner in C, I learned a fancy way to allocate the memory with `struct{}` to replace something like `ch1Buffer = calloc(u32Size, sizeof *ch1Buffer);`and put them outside of the `int main{}` to boost up the calculation speed.
However, I got an error on my variable `x` saying: `This declaration has no storage class or type specifier`, you can see the annotation on the side of the code. Should I declared the variable `x` or?

Here is my example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// New way for memory allocation 
struct {
    float ch1Buffer;
    double ch2Buffer;
    double ch2newBuffer;
} *x;
x = calloc(10, sizeof * x); // The error happened on the left side "x": This declaration has no storage class or type specifier

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    const int u32Size = 10;
    float* ch1Buffer = NULL;
    double* ch2Buffer = NULL;
    double* ch2newBuffer=NULL;
    
    
    int pBuffer[] = { 10,2,10,2,10,5,10,5,10,2 };
    int* pi16Buffer = pBuffer;

    // Old way for memory allocation
    //ch1Buffer = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch1Buffer);
    //ch2Buffer = (double*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch2Buffer);
    //ch2newBuffer = (double*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof * ch2Buffer);

    

    // De-interveal the data to ch1Buffer and ch2Buffer
    for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
    {
        ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2];
        ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
    }

    // Use memcpy to pick out the data we are interested
    memcpy(ch2newBuffer, &ch2Buffer[2], 2 * sizeof(ch2Buffer[0]));

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %f\n", i, *ch2newBuffer);
        ch2newBuffer++;
    }


    free(ch1Buffer);
    free(ch2Buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot call functions while initializing global variables in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky But even I put the `struct{}` inside the main, another error occurred: `a value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity "struct<unnamed>*"`

Comment: You cannot do this. Neither C nor C++ works this way. As far as the later compilation error -- this is because you are compiling code as C++, but you're really writing C code. C++ requires an explicit cast from `void *`, which the C `calloc` function returns. C and C++ are two completely different languages. If your intent is to write C code, use a C compiler. If your intent is to learn and write C++, forget about `calloc`, `printf`, and others, and use the type-safe C++ equivalents instead, see your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: @Kevin you need `#include <stdlib.h>` for `calloc`. But that looks like another question. Ask a new question for this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows the OP has not made any effort to fix the problems themself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a `malloc` or `calloc` outside main or any other function. You can declare it at the beginning of your code if you need it as a global variable but you'll need to allocate the memory inside the main for example.

```
typedef struct mystruct {
  float ch1Buffer;
  double ch2Buffer;
  double ch2newBuffer;
}mystruct;

mystruct* x;

int main (void) {
    x = calloc(10, sizeof(mystruct)); // array of your structs
    if (!x) { // always check calloc return value
        perror("calloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* do stuff */

    return 0;
}
```

Also I would suggest giving self-explanatory names to your structs for a better understanding of what it represents.

Comment: Thanks! But I still got an error on the line of `x = calloc(10, sizeof(mystruct));` saying `ErroC2440'=': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'mystruct *'
`

Comment: That's a common compiler error, just add this before the calloc: `x = (mystruct*)calloc(10, sizeof(mystruct));`. Explicit casting the calloc to the type of your variable, which in this case is `mystruct*` should have fixed your problem. It's a good habit to always do this cast for `malloc`, `calloc`, because some compilers won't run.

Comment: Thanks, but here bumps into the problem I met before when using `struct{}` to allocate memory. The error occurred in `De-interveal ` part, `ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2];` saying `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF719D41A9B in Examplefordebug.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.` looks like the memory didn't allocate sucessfully?

Comment: In fact, I am trying to mimic the data processing when my DAQ card acquiring data through channel 1 and channel 2. The rule of the data filling to the memory is ch1ch2ch1ch2.... So that's why I wrote a `for` loop to 'divide' and get these two channels from `pi16Buffer[i]`. Maybe better approach to fit this kind of memory allocation?

Comment: Ask another question about the new problem you're encountering. I'm not sure I can help you with that, the calloc use is fine anyway, the problem is not related to it's use anymore. Hope my help was usefull for the first part anyway :)

Comment: Thanks! I gave you the credit! At least I confirmed that I didn’t make a mistake in using struct{}

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a example to use components of each members. Similar to the above anwers, the pointer is defined as a global, and allocated in main(). This Not a good pratice, just for demo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10
struct xxx {
    float f1;
    double d2;
    double d3;
};
typedef struct xxx mytype;
mytype *x;
void print_mytype()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) printf("x[%d] = %f, %lf, %lf\n", i, x[i].f1, x[i].d2, x[i].d3);
    return;
}
void setdata()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
      x[i].f1 = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
      x[i].d2 = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
      x[i].d3 = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    }
}
int main()
{
    x = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(mytype));
    setdata();
    print_mytype();
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the posted code does not compile!

Here is what the compiler says about the code:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o" 
untitled1.c:9:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
    9 | x = calloc(10, sizeof * x); // The error happened on the left side "x": This declaration has no storage class or type specifier
      | ^
      
untitled1.c:9:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘x’ [-Wimplicit-int]

untitled1.c:9:1: error: conflicting types for ‘x’

untitled1.c:8:4: note: previous declaration of ‘x’ was here
    8 | } *x;
      |    ^
      
untitled1.c:9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘calloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    9 | x = calloc(10, sizeof * x); // The error happened on the left side "x": This declaration has no storage class or type specifier
      |     ^~~~~~
      
untitled1.c:9:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘calloc’

untitled1.c:2:1: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘calloc’
    1 | #include <stdio.h>
  +++ |+#include <stdlib.h>
    2 |
    
untitled1.c:9:23: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
    9 | x = calloc(10, sizeof * x); // The error happened on the left side "x": This declaration has no storage class or type specifier
      |                       ^~~
      
untitled1.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled1.c:33:22: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   33 |         ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2];
      |                      ^~
      
untitled1.c:38:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   38 |     memcpy(ch2newBuffer, &ch2Buffer[2], 2 * sizeof(ch2Buffer[0]));
      |     ^~~~~~
      
untitled1.c:38:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’

untitled1.c:2:1: note: include ‘<string.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘memcpy’
    1 | #include <stdio.h>
  +++ |+#include <string.h>
    2 |
    
untitled1.c:47:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘free’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   47 |     free(ch1Buffer);
      |     ^~~~
      
untitled1.c:47:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’

untitled1.c:47:5: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘free’

untitled1.c:13:11: warning: unused variable ‘n’ [-Wunused-variable]
   13 |     int i,n;
      |           ^
      
Compilation failed.
```

Suggest you fix those problems in the code, that you can, before asking us about any problems that you cannot fix.

As the error messages say:

1. add the statement:

   #include <stdlib.h>
2. add the statement:

   #include <string.h>

We are unlikely to help you when the code you post clearly indicates that you have not put any effort into solving the problem(s) your self.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, besides, if you think I didn't do any effort than you can decide don't answer or disturb ;)

Comment: @Kevin,  When you post code that shows no effort (on your part) you will get marked down and see comments about 'no effort'.   Suggest: fix those things you can, like the missing header files, then post an 'edit' section into your question